# While loop not ending even with a boolean test applied

Tags: java, while-loop

```
boolean flag = true;
   while(flag == true){
        System.out.println("Type in the item u wish to purchase: chocolate'c',apple'a',meat'm',eggs'e',pencils'p'   Bill:'b'");
        sign = in.next();
        ch = sign.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Enter the quantity");
        amount = in.nextInt();
        if(ch == 'c'){
            Item_sel.add("Chocolate");
            quantity.add(amount);
            Stock[0]=Stock[0]-amount;               
        }else if(ch == 'a'){
            Item_sel.add("apples");
            quantity.add(amount);
            Stock[1]=Stock[1]-amount;   
        }else if(ch == 'm'){
            Item_sel.add("meat");
            quantity.add(amount);
            Stock[2]=Stock[2]-amount;   
        }else if(ch == 'e'){
            Item_sel.add("eggs");
            quantity.add(amount);
            Stock[3]=Stock[3]-amount;   
        }else if(ch == 'p'){
            Item_sel.add("pencils");
            quantity.add(amount);
            Stock[4]=Stock[4]-amount;   
        }
        if(ch == 'b'){
            String[] myArray = new String[Item_sel.size()];
            Item_sel.toArray(myArray);
            int[] myArray2 = new int[quantity.size()];
            quantity.toArray(myArray);
            change(myArray,myArray2);
            flag = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then the flag is never set (and kept) at false for the loop condition to end..

Comment: ya but the flag starts as true and is supposed to end as false wats the problem

Comment: ch never equals b to change the boolean.

Comment: why what if the user inputs 'b'

Comment: @user3901683 What *is* the problem? Attach a debugger and step through the code. Take note of what happens - is it expected?

Comment: (I can say that `ch == 'b'` is never true, if that is the code executed. Find out why.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *should* exit, assuming the code you've shown is accurate, and you're actually entering a `b` at some point. Perhaps your *actual* problem is that it asks for a quantity even when you enter `b` for the bill. It seems to me that you may see that as the loop not ending.

If you enter `b` followed by a quantity and it still doesn't exit then I'm obviously wrong.

If it *does* exit after the amount, then it's simply a matter of restructuring the code so that it doesn't ask for a quantity when `b` is entered.

That's probably just a simple matter of replacing:

```
System.out.println("Enter the quantity");
amount = in.nextInt();
```

with:

```
if (ch != 'b') {
    System.out.println("Enter the quantity");
    amount = in.nextInt();
}
```

For example, the following (slightly modified to make complete) program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       boolean flag = true;
       while(flag == true){
           System.out.println("Type in 'c', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'p' or 'b'");
           String sign = in.next();
           char ch = sign.charAt(0);
           System.out.println("Enter the quantity");
           int amount = in.nextInt();
           if(ch == 'c'){
           }else if(ch == 'a'){
           }else if(ch == 'm'){
           }else if(ch == 'e'){
           }else if(ch == 'p'){
           }
           if(ch == 'b'){
               flag = false;
           }
       }
       System.out.println("Done.");
   }
}
```

looks like `b` doesn't exit, at least initially. But, when you enter the amount it does:

```
Type in 'c', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'p' or 'b'
c
Enter the quantity
3
Type in 'c', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'p' or 'b'
p
Enter the quantity
2
Type in 'c', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'p' or 'b'
b
Enter the quantity
99
Done.
```

Fixing it as suggested:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       boolean flag = true;
       while(flag == true){
           System.out.println("Type in 'c', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'p' or 'b'");
           String sign = in.next();
           char ch = sign.charAt(0);
           if (ch != 'b') {
               System.out.println("Enter the quantity");
               int amount = in.nextInt();
           }
           if(ch == 'c'){
           }else if(ch == 'a'){
           }else if(ch == 'm'){
           }else if(ch == 'e'){
           }else if(ch == 'p'){
           }
           if(ch == 'b'){
               flag = false;
           }
       }
       System.out.println("Done.");
   }
}
```

removes the unwanted amount input for type `b`:

```
Type in 'c', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'p' or 'b'
c
Enter the quantity
3
Type in 'c', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'p' or 'b'
p
Enter the quantity
2
Type in 'c', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'p' or 'b'
b
Done.
```

---

And, just as an aside, please don't do things like:

```
while (flag == true) ...
while (userInsane == false) ...
```

If your variables are named nicely, it's much more readable to just use the boolean as is, such as:

```
while (moreInput) ...
while (! dataStreamClosed) ...
```